# What is the best app for search and play youtube videos?

Tags: video, youtube, video-player, video-streaming

I google it for an app that will search&play youtube videos.
The ones that I found are either not working nor there are simple to use.
Among these apps are Minitube, VLC, mps-youtube, Atraci.

Are there any other simple solutions you can help me with, please?

Comment: What features do you want? This question is very subjective without list of features that you search.

Comment: I already found SMPlayer. JoKeR helped me on that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend SMPlayer it's my fav. it's got Youtube browser built-in.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rvm/smplayer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install smplayer smtube smplayer-themes smplayer-skins
```

Alternative is [Youtube Viewer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612919/youtube-app-for-ubuntu-14-04-and-later).

P.S.

Because of Google policies and restrictions if you can't play VEVO videos for now this is how it's gonna be.